# flask-mail and twilio have same function names called Message(). how to resolve name clash

Tags: python, flask, twilio, flask-restful, flask-mail

```
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse 
from flask_mail import Mail, Message


flask_mail.Message("hi") 
Message.Message("hi")
```

How do I explicitly tell the interpreter which package the method/function belongs to ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking:

```
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse as twili_message
from flask_mail import Mail as flask_mail, Message as flask_message
```